# adding UTM paramaters to urls of product in bulk - postgresql django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, url, utm

I'm trying to find a way to add `Utm paramaters` to every single `link` column in my `postresql` using `django`.

The links looks to something like this:

```
https://www.headout.com/tour/5696/united-states/las-vegas/eldorado-canyon-techatticup-mine-tour-premium-group-tour
```

The Utm like the following:

```
?utm_source=uvergo&utm_medium=ref&utm_campaign=meta
```

And the result would be this:

```
https://www.headout.com/tour/5696/united-states/las-vegas/eldorado-canyon-techatticup-mine-tour-premium-group-tour?utm_source=uvergo&utm_medium=ref&utm_campaign=meta
```

Is there a way to add the parameter in bulk without having to reindex all my datas again? In the views.py or something?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

```
LinkModel.objects.all().update(url=F('url') + '?utm_source=uvergo&utm_medium=ref&utm_campaign=meta')
```

You say you don't want to re-index your data, you should be aware that any change to an indexed field will cause postgres to "re-index". If you really don't want this to happen you can drop the index and then recreate it after the update [see the docs on creating indexes concurrently](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY)

Comment: Thanks so doing this should update all my data in the url column by adding this parameter at the end? Just want to make sure that it won't delete anything!

Comment: I get the following error when i do it:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: character varying + unknown
LINE 1: ...uggest" = ("search_usersuggestion"."text_suggest" + '?utm_so...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.